# Smalltalk syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, smalltalk, seaside

I'm building a Seaside application and I'm searching for a way to highlight some code snippets on the browser with JS.
I found highlight.js which support Smalltalk syntax but it doesn't work.
I add this [script](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/languages/smalltalk.min.js) and hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); in the header but it doesn't work.

Probably I miss something but what?

Comment: please add some code which you tried to get the desired results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use highlight.js from CDN:

```
<link href='http://yandex.st/highlightjs/8.0/styles/sunburst.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='http://yandex.st/highlightjs/8.0/highlight.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

I also define a format function like:

```
function format(){
    var b=document.getElementsByTagName(&quot;pre&quot;);
    for (i=0;i&lt;b.length;i++) {
        hljs.tabReplace = &#39;  &#39;; // 2 spaces
        b[i].style.fontSize = &#39;0.9em&#39;;
        hljs.highlightBlock(b[i],&#39;  &#39;,false);
    }
}
```

and use

```
<pre class="smalltalk"><code>……</code></pre>
```

for highlightable block. Then I call `format()` when the page is loaded (or a dynamic content with code is loaded into page)